# Exiting from ri (ruby documentation viewer) in Mac OS

Tags: ruby, macos, ri

Any time I want to use ruby's `ri` tool, (e.g. after typing something like `ri GC`), after it shows the documentation, I can find no way of exiting it and none of the usual key combinations for terminating a command-line command works. Because of that I'm forced to close the whole terminal window to continue my works.

How can I quit normally from ri after it showed documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to simply type `q` and it will exit.